# Expected Value of Y = A+B

Tags: probability

Following Situation:

A country has a population of 90% poor people (P) and 10% rich ones (R).
The income of a random sample of "Rich" is:

$\mu_{R} = 1000 $ with a standard deviation of $ \sigma_{R} = 300$

The income of a random sample of "Poor" is:

$\mu_{R} = 100 $ with a standard deviation of $ \sigma_{R} = 30$

Which EV and wich standard deviation has the income of a random sample of the Neverland Citizen?

I've tried to make use of the linearity of EV. Let $Y := \frac{1}{10} \cdot R + \frac{9}{10} \cdot P $

$EV(Y) = \frac{1}{10}EV(R) + \frac{9}{10}E(P) = 190$

Hence $\sigma^2_{Y} = \frac{1}{10}^2 \cdot \sigma^2_{R} + \frac{9}{10}^2 \cdot \sigma_{P}^2 + 2cov(R,P) $

Is this a correct approach? If yes: how can I compute the covariance?

Comment: The covariance of independent variables is 0.

Comment: Sounds rather grim, top 10% make more than the rest combined.

Comment: @tomasz, grim? It's a **vast** improvement on the current wealth distribution in the US and UK (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wealth_inequality_in_the_United_States)

Comment: @davin: I was being a little sarcastic there. Note that the distribution of *earnings* is not *that* bad, even if it's still pretty bad, especially if you consider the fact that rich people may tend to pay their taxes abroad. See this (top 10% seems to be just a bit less than 50% of total earnings): http://www.heritage.org/federalbudget/top10-percent-income-earners .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event that the sample of citizen is a sample of poor, then $P(A)=p$ with $p=\frac9{10}$ and the income $Y$ of the sample of citizen is
$$
Y=\mathbf 1_{A}\,P+\mathbf 1_{A^c}\,R.
$$
Assuming that $A$ is independent of $R$ and $P$, one gets
$$
E(Y)=pE(P)+qE(R),
$$
with $q=1-p$, hence your numerical result $E(Y)=190$ is correct, and
$$
Y^2=\mathbf 1_{A}\,P^2+\mathbf 1_{A^c}\,R^2,
$$
hence
$$
E(Y^2)=pE(P^2)+qE(R^2).
$$
This implies
$$
\sigma^2_Y=pE(P^2)+qE(R^2)-(pE(P)+qE(R))^2,
$$
that is,
$$
\sigma^2_Y=p\sigma^2_P+q\sigma^2_R+pq(E(P)-E(R))^2,
$$
which is slightly different from your suggestion (which I cannot explain, by the way).